# Can Spark be configured to listen on multiple network interfaces/ip addresses?

Tags: apache-spark

The nodes in my Spark cluster have two network interfaces each, one public and one private. Using the `SPARK_MASTER_IP` environment variable, I can [configure Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/spark-standalone.html) to listen on port 7077 on one or the other ip address.

For example:

```
netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 10.x.x.x:7077           :::*                    LISTEN      43403/java
```

Is there any way to configure Spark to listen on port 7077 on both the public and private interface at the same time?

Comment: What did you try?